# How to use spark.connect.grpc.interceptor.classes conf

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm trying to use spark connect and a I need a interceptor server to do things like authentication, logging etc. There is this parameter `spark.connect.grpc.interceptor.classes` that do this, but I don't know how to use it, the most basically interceptor that I wrote was:

```
import io.grpc.Metadata;
import io.grpc.Metadata.Key;
import io.grpc.ServerCall;
import io.grpc.ServerCall.Listener;
import io.grpc.ServerCallHandler;
import io.grpc.ServerInterceptor;
import io.grpc.Status;
import io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException;

public class TestInterceptor implements ServerInterceptor {

    public <ReqT, RespT> Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(final ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> serverCall, final Metadata metadata, final ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> serverCallHandler) {

        System.out.println("Hello inside of interceptor");

        return serverCallHandler.startCall(serverCall, metadata);
    }
}
```

and I'm running spark connect with:

```
./start-connect-server.sh \
    --packages org.apache.spark:spark-connect_2.12:3.4.1 \
    --conf spark.connect.grpc.interceptor.classes=<path-to-java-file>
```

However when I execute this I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /opt/spark/sbin/TestInterceptor.java
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:225)...
```

Is there any example on how to use this `spark.connect.grpc.interceptor.classes` parameter? I should provide the full path of my java file or something else? The interceptor that I wrote is correct?